# Pics of my greeting cards in a photo booth, but they are always light on top and dark on the bottom

Tags: exposure, lighting

I take pics of my greeting cards in a nice photo booth, but they are always light on top and dark on the bottom. Using my cell phone camera and a light gray background.

Comment: How is the scene being lit? What type of lighting is being used? An example would be very helpful.

Comment: I am using this:  https://www.amazon.com/StudioFX-H9004S-Photography-Continuous-Lighting/dp/B00TOWZDE8/ref=sr_1_103_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=lighting+booth&qid=1622947335&sr=8-103-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyNlpOTlFVNEVVTFImZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAzMjc4MzEyODJNWjdaWDUwNUFBJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAzNjMyNTgyUllMMDBRN1JOUk1EJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfbXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==

Comment: Here is an example of how the pics are light at the top and dark t the bottom. I think I nded to somehow add front lights, as there are only 3 lights---top and 2 sides.

Comment: https://www.etsy.com/listing/1019201167/handmade-4th-of-july-usa-card?ref=shop_home_feat_2

Comment: Another example of dark on the bottom....  https://www.etsy.com/listing/1009830850/handmade-thinking-of-you-card?ref=shop_home_active_43

Comment: What is your exposure time ("shutter speed")? What about ISO? This information should be in the EXIF information of the photos. If you right click on the photo on a Windows computer and select 'Properties', you will usually also be able to see shooting info such as aperture, ISO, and exposure time/shutter speed/Tv (for 'time value').

Comment: Are you mostly concerned about the brightness of your cards being even? Or are you also concerned about evenly lighting the background?

Comment: Hi Pam. Please edit your question to include the pictures directly, rather than just linking to an Etsy page. If the images become unavailable in the future (such as removing the product listings), this question and its answers would be much less useful. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit hard to answer, due to the lack of detail.
What you see is most probably caused by your lighting setup.

From what I read I understand, that you use 1 softbox at the top and 2 at the sides. This will create even lighting horizontally, but cause a brightness gradation from top to bottom.

Without seeing the exact scene, you are lighting, it is hard to provide a solution, but here are some things to try out:

- Adding a front/bottom light
- Using a white piece of cardboard or similar as a reflector from the bottom.
- Using the "Inverse Square Law" by placing the lights farther away. This will decrease the loss of light in the distance between top to bottom, evening out the gradation. However, the overall loss of light might be too much on constant lights. Plus the shadows will become harder.